# HTML Helper Kendo Button

Tags: kendo-ui

I am unable to get Button() builder in view page, my page is designed as follows..

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
<h2>ButtonKendoHelper</h2>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="~/Scripts/Kendo/Styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/Kendo/Styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
 @(Html.Kendo().**button()**
</body>
</html>
```

when i entered "b", it is showing MobileButton Controls.
may i know why i am unable to get Button Builder?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an old version which doesn't yet support the Kendo Button. Try upgrading to the latest version.